# Visual Studio Python Tests, Debugger not hitting breakpoints

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

**Problem:**

When trying to Run Debug on a Test, breakpoints are not hit. The breakpoint symbol displays a message that the

> breakpoint cannot be hit because symbols where not loaded for that
> file (translated)

In the Output I can see that for some modules the message

> Module was loaded without symbols (translated)

appears, but I do not know how to solve this message.

BUT When I execute the start file of my application ( with debugging) breakpoints are hit normally.

Addition
When using the menu option Project -> start with debugging with a test file the breakpoints are hit. But not when clicking on a test in the test explorer and using debug.

**Background:**

- IDE: Visual Studio 2019 and 2022
- Language: Python 3.9
- Testframework: unittest
- I made sure that the version is Debug and Any CPU

I was able to work normally for a while but the debugger seemlingly broke without me changing any configurations or installing any modules.

**Already Tried:**

- De-/activating Only own code ( Debug options )
- Restarting the IDE
- Updating the IDE
- Deleting visual studio folders and caches
- I do not have any "module" window to try and load resources
- I do not have any option to "cleane solution"

I am aware that there are other similar questions avaiable but the answers on those do not work for me as most of them are realted to C# or C++ project files and I specifically have problems with `python unittest`